# How to get the ActualWidth of a auto-fit width column in a listview?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I have a really simple wpf listview as

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" MinHeight="0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="columnsGridView">
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And I bind it with some class to display

```
aaa bbb ccc
```

and in the listview's SizeChanged function I ran

```
            foreach (var item in columnsGridView.Columns.Select((v, i)=> new {v, i}))
            {
                if (someCondition)
                {
                    width += item.v.ActualWidth;
                }
            }
```

But I find the ActualWidth is always 0 while Width is NaN (which is what I need)

If I specify it's width then I can get the width of course. But how can I get a auto-width item's width while in the listview's SizeChanged func?

P.S.
I notice that outside this function I can get their widths..

Comment: Just thinking... new{v,i}? Doesn´t that mean, that you actually create a new object? That would also explain why it´s actual width is 0... I could be wrong though -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had to define at least one column in order to show items:

```
 <ListView MinHeight="0" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" >

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView  x:Name="GridViewInstance">
                <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" Header="First Name" />
            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.Items>
            <sys:String>1</sys:String>
            <sys:String>2</sys:String>
            <sys:String>3</sys:String>
            <sys:String>4</sys:String>
            <sys:String>5</sys:String>
            <sys:String>6</sys:String>
            <sys:String>7</sys:String>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
```

Now the items are shown with the LoadedEvent you can get the actual widths:

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var test = GridViewInstance.Columns[0].ActualWidth;
    }
```

And now you can operate as you need